# SqlProvider overload

Tags: mybatis

can sqlprovider overload

```
    @InsertProvider(type = MovieCatSqlProvider.class)
    int insertMovieCat(String movieId,String catId);

    @InsertProvider(type = MovieCatSqlProvider.class)
    int insertMovieCat(Movie movie,CatTag catTag);

     public String insertMovieCat(String movieId,String catId) {
            return new SQL(){{
                INSERT_INTO("movie_cat");
                VALUES("movie_id", "#{movieId}");
                VALUES("cat_id", "#{catId}");

            }}.toString();
        }

        public String insertMovieCat(Movie movie,CatTag catTag) {
            return new SQL(){{
                INSERT_INTO("movie_cat");
                VALUES("movie_id", "#{movie.movieId}");
                VALUES("cat_id", "#{catTag.catId}");

            }}.toString();
        }
```

the exception is 
Cannot resolve the provider method because 'insertMovieCat' is found multiple in SqlProvider 'top.curryguy.ossjava.dao.MovieCatDao$MovieCatSqlProvider'.

i want to overload method

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded methods are not supported at this point (version 3.5.1).
Here is a [feature request issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1482) and a [proposed fix](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1519).

Comment: Unfortunately，i‘ve spent tow hours to found this .Thanks for your kind help.I've read the commit of proposed fix ,but i did't want to use it .It is a good solution and i hope the authorities would fix it as soon as possible.